# If $ \frac{a}{b} < \frac{c}{d} $, then $ \frac{a}{b} < \frac{a + c}{b + d} < \frac{c}{d} $

Tags: inequality

Assume $b > 0,\ d > 0$. Assume:
$$ \frac{a}{b} < \frac{c}{d} $$.

Prove that:

$$ \frac{a}{b} < \frac{a + c}{b + d} < \frac{c}{d} $$.

I would like to find an intuitive way to solve such a question. I know that there are two steps to this question: we must solve for the first inequality, and then the second. In the first inequality, I know I must somehow show that $\frac{a + c}{b + d}- \frac{a}{b} > 0 $. How could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way is to transform, in this case. Your original inequality is equivalent to $ad<bc$.

The first inequality you try to prove is equivalent to $a(b+d)<b(a+c)$. This in turn is equivalent to $ab+ad<ab+bc$, which is true since $ad<bc$ by assumption.