# Showing that $a(b)^{-1} < (a+c)(b+d)^{-1} < c(d)^{-1}$ when $a(b)^{-1} < c(d)^{-1}$ and $b,d > 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know that $a(b)^{-1}  b(b+d)^{-1} + c(d)^{-1}  d(b+d)^{-1} = (a+c)(b+d)^{-1}$.  Can this identity help me to prove the inequality?

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/751155/42969.

Comment: there is no Information about a and b and they are also reals and not integers.

Comment: Have a look at the second link. Also the *answers* in the first link prove the general statement about real numbers.